# Find matching pattern from string and make a list of that pattern string

Tags: c#

Check the code bellow. Here on `imgList` string list i want to find all matching pattern `[img=`. So basically i want to say c# that: give me list of whole value which contains `[img=`. So it will find matching start with `[img=` until `]`. I already tried `Regex.Matches` like bellow but it not reruns me proper value in list which should be `[img=15]` and `[img=16]`

c#

```
  var imgList = new List<string>();
            string text = "abcdef[img=15]ghijklmnop[img=16]qrstuvwxyz";
           
            MatchCollection matchList = Regex.Matches(text, @"^.*[img=$]");
            imgList = matchList.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: You need `\[img=\d+\]`. Or `\[img=[^\]]+\]` if "img=" doesn't have to be followed by digits.

Comment: yes that was correct @41686d6564

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern \[img=.*?\]

"\[" matches the character "[" literally (case sensitive)

"img=" matches the characters "img=" literally (case sensitive)

".*?" matches any character (except for line terminators)
"*?" Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible,
expanding as needed (lazy)

"\]" matches the character "]" literally (case sensitive)